# Redireccionamiento a directorio raiz con JavaScript en Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente problema : Ejecuto mi aplicacion e inicia en la pagina default.aspx , ejecuto la siguiente funcion desde un boton

```
function RedirectPage() { location.href = ../View/otherpage.aspx;}
```

ahora nesecito regresar a default.aspx y ejecuto esta funcion pero no me funciona ...que estoy haciendo mal??

```
function RedirectPage() { location.href = ../default.aspx;}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: *no me funciona*: ¿Qué sucede? ¿Recibes un error? ¿Cual error? etc...  Y en general, evita los paths relativos (`../`), te evitas muchos problemas.

Comment: se recarga la pagina donde estoy otherpage.aspx

Comment: para urls es mejor que uses algún urlhelper que te entregue la ruta completa donde quieres ser dirigido. en mvc se usa URL.Action busca un equivalente para aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ruta debe ir entrecomillada:

```
function RedirectPage() { location.href = "../View/otherpage.aspx";}
```

Si tu pagina otherpage.aspx se carga dentro de un iframe deberás utilizar la propiedad:

```
window.parent.location.href
```

o bien si quieres asegurar llegar al nivel superior:

```
window.top.location.href
```